# Proof of Muirhead's inequality

Tags: inequality, reference-request, muirhead-inequality

I have seen Muirhead's inequality being stated and used in many, many places, but I haven't ever seen a proof. Does someone have a reference or simple proof for this result?

Comment: Steele's book on inequalities?

Answer (score 1):

For non-negative integer powers we can use an induction and we can get a sum of squares.

For non-negative real powers we can use doubly stochastic matrices. See about this:

A.W.Marshal, I.Olkin "Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applicaitions",

Mathematics in science and engineering, Volume 143, 1979.